# Android SDK tools rev 10 and eclipse helios not working

Tags: android, eclipse

When I updated sdk tools to revision 10 all my projects started failing.

Apparently a build clean would erase the gen folder and the build will fail because of missing R.java.

This also happens with the build that eclipse does when starting, so if you close eclipse with all your projects ok, when you start eclipse again the projects will fail.

Comment: I had this problem too. After a lot of project cleans and full rebuilds, it eventually went away...

Comment: Is a common problem, at least for me, everytime i update the SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try Project -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties?

Comment: That works but it's not permanent, when I restart eclipse the problem reappears.